# How to make Facebook share the featuterd image from url on Wordpress

Tags: images, facebook

I use this function to add the featured image from url on wordpress "[Is it possible set a featured image with external image URL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158491/is-it-possible-set-a-featured-image-with-external-image-url)", but when i share the post on Facebook, Facebook doesn't grab the featured image from url, it grabs any images from the sidebar or from the related content.
I added meta tags but it didn't work.
I think it needs a function to tell Facebook to grab the featured image from url.

Comment: What meta tags did you add? Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7623986/1094518) -- is that what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

[Featured Image From URL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-image-from-url) plugin contains social tags. So you can share your posts and the external featured image will be shown on the Social Networks.

[image]