# Can we use featured image as third party website image URL

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, import, thumbnails

In my case we are getting some post list from third party and import in our custom post type.

My question is, Is we can use post featured image as third party website image URL instead of upload featured image.

Answer (score 1):

There are plugins that could be used to achieve this. 
 To do it manually add the following code to your theme's function.php

```
// Check if URL is image
function url_is_image( $url ) {
    if ( ! filter_var( $url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL ) ) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $ext = array( 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png' );
    $info = (array) pathinfo( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_PATH ) );
    return isset( $info['extension'] )
        && in_array( strtolower( $info['extension'] ), $ext, TRUE );
}

// Add the URL textbox in Fratured image
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'thumbnail_url_field' );

function thumbnail_url_field( $html ) {
    global $post;
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_thumbnail_ext_url', TRUE ) ? : "";
    $nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'thumbnail_ext_url_' . $post->ID . get_current_blog_id() );
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="thumbnail_ext_url_nonce" value="' 
        . esc_attr( $nonce ) . '">';
    $html .= '<div><p>' . __('Or', 'txtdomain') . '</p>';
    $html .= '<p>' . __( 'Enter the url for external image', 'txtdomain' ) . '</p>';
    $html .= '<p><input type="url" name="thumbnail_ext_url" value="' . $value . '"></p>';
    if ( ! empty($value) && url_is_image( $value ) ) {
        $html .= '<p><img style="max-width:150px;height:auto;" src="' 
            . esc_url($value) . '"></p>';
        $html .= '<p>' . __( 'Leave url blank to remove.', 'txtdomain' ) . '</p>';
    }
    $html .= '</div>';
    return $html;
}

// Save the thumbnail with post
add_action( 'save_post', 'thumbnail_url_field_save', 10, 2 );

function thumbnail_url_field_save( $pid, $post ) {
    $cap = $post->post_type === 'page' ? 'edit_page' : 'edit_post';
    if (
        ! current_user_can( $cap, $pid )
        || ! post_type_supports( $post->post_type, 'thumbnail' )
        || defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' )
    ) {
        return;
    }
    $action = 'thumbnail_ext_url_' . $pid . get_current_blog_id();
    $nonce = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'thumbnail_ext_url_nonce', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $url = filter_input( INPUT_POST,  'thumbnail_ext_url', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL );
    if (
        empty( $nonce )
        || ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, $action )
        || ( ! empty( $url ) && ! url_is_image( $url ) )
    ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( ! empty( $url ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $pid, '_thumbnail_ext_url', esc_url($url) );
        if ( ! get_post_meta( $pid, '_thumbnail_id', TRUE ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $pid, '_thumbnail_id', 'by_url' );
        }
    } elseif ( get_post_meta( $pid, '_thumbnail_ext_url', TRUE ) ) {
        delete_post_meta( $pid, '_thumbnail_ext_url' );
        if ( get_post_meta( $pid, '_thumbnail_id', TRUE ) === 'by_url' ) {
            delete_post_meta( $pid, '_thumbnail_id' );
        }
    }
}

add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'thumbnail_external_replace', 10, PHP_INT_MAX );

function thumbnail_external_replace( $html, $post_id ) {
    $url =  get_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_ext_url', TRUE );
    if ( empty( $url ) || ! url_is_image( $url ) ) {
        return $html;
    }
    $alt = get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id ) . ' ' .  __( 'thumbnail', 'txtdomain' );
    $attr = array( 'alt' => $alt );
    $attr = apply_filters( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', $attr, NULL );
    $attr = array_map( 'esc_attr', $attr );
    $html = sprintf( '<img src="%s"', esc_url($url) );
    foreach ( $attr as $name => $value ) {
        $html .= " $name=" . '"' . $value . '"';
    }
    $html .= ' />';
    return $html;
}
```

Refer this answer for more details - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158568/110516

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/148305)

Comment: Apologies! I have edited my answer.